# Dynamically update aggregate row in DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a DataTable of people with multiple series' of data.  The people can be grouped into a Region, Team, or Region and Team.  I'm trying to create a row in the DataTable that will dynamically aggregate (sum) the values of the highest level of the table.

I see the following three scenarios possible:

1. Both Region and Team Leader are included in the table, then the aggregate will be based on Region.
2. Only Region included (Team Leader excluded), then aggregate based on Region.
3. Only Team Leader included (Region excluded), then aggregate based on Team Leader.

Here is a JS Fiddle with what I've got.  I can't seem to figure out how to get an aggregate row to be dynamic.  Anytime I do anything to the table from here I seem to break everything.  Any help is welcome!  Thanks!

https://jsfiddle.net/mrpicc/2tpkgm9n/

**HTML**

```
 <body>


<div class = "row" >
    <div class = 'col-sm-4'>
        <div class = "well" align="center"> 
            <b> Select Value Type </b> <br> <br>
            <form>
                <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio" value="current">Option 1</label>
                <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio" value="mtd">Option 2</label>
                <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio" value="rolling">Option 3</label>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class = 'col-sm-4'>
        <div class = "well" align="center"> 
            <b> Add / Drop Columns </b> <br> <br> 
            <form>
                <label class="checkbox-inline" >
                    <input type="checkbox" value="true" checked=true data-column="0"> 
                        Region </label>

                <label class="checkbox-inline" >
                    <input type="checkbox" value="true" checked=true data-column="1"> 
                        Team Leader </label>

            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-10">
        <div class="panel panel-default">

            <div class="panel-body">
                  <table id="example" class="display" width="100%">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th rowspan = "2" align = "center">Region</th>
                            <th rowspan = "2" align = "center">Leader</th>
                            <th rowspan = "2" align = "center">Member</th>
                            <th colspan = "2" align = "justfiy">Group A</th>
                            <th colspan = "2" align = "justfiy">Group B</th>
                            <th colspan = "2" align = "justfiy">Group C</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Series 1</th>
                            <th>Series 2</th>
                            <th>Series 3</th>
                            <th>Series 4</th>
                            <th>Series 5</th>
                            <th>Series 6</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                  </table>                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


  </body>
```

**JavaScript**

```
 $(function() {
    var $radios = $('input:radio[name=optradio]');
    if($radios.is(':checked') === false) {
        $radios.filter('[value=rolling]').prop('checked', true);
    }
});

$(document).ready( function () {
  var data = [
    ['West', 'John', 'Peter', '-4', '54,164', '-4','546,565', '0','25,547'],
    ['West', 'John', 'John', '29,267','64,876', '2,677','987,654', '0','54,546'],
    ['West', 'Mark', 'Mark', '546,203','554,421', '548,284','5,654,421', '0','65,871'],
    ['East', 'Jim', 'Jim', '164,014','246,698', '166,031','2,546,698', '0','524,652'],
    ['East', 'Jim', 'John', '816,031','557,124', '267,978','5,657,124', '210,412','654,421'],
    ['East', 'Tammy', 'Phil', '3,500','56,654', '3,500','564,654', '0','141,654'],
    ['North', 'Paul', 'Dave', '142,405','5,352', '225,257','5,322', '79,228','87,657'],
    ['North', 'Paul', 'Kourtney', '158,634','576,451', '158,634', '576,451', '0','54,254'],

  ];
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    data: data,
    rowsGroup: [
                // Always the array (!) of the column-selectors in specified order to which rows groupping is applied
                // (column-selector could be any of specified in https://datatables.net/reference/type/column-selector)
          0,
          1

    ]});

$('label.checkbox-inline input').on( 'click', function (e) {
        //e.preventDefault();

        // Get the column API object
        var column = table.column( $(this).attr('data-column') );
        console.log(`this is ${$(this).attr('data-column')}`);
        // Toggle the visibility
        column.visible( ! column.visible() );
    } );

} );
```